# How to calculate sum of expenses of the entries made at current date using LINQ or anything?

Tags: .net, model-view-controller

I want to calculate the sum of the expenditure made on current date's entry. 
this is my model.

```
public class ExpenditureViewModel
{
    public decimal PaidPrice { get; set; } 
    public DateTime CreatedDate {get; set;}       
}
```

this is the DashboardViewmodel

```
public decimal TotalExpenses { get; set; }
```

this code will sum up all the expenses made but i want of the current date.

```
model.TotalExpenses = ent.Expenditures.Sum(m => m.PaidPrice);
```

Comment: Include just enough code to allow others to solve the question. For help with this, read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). In this case, **please remove properties that are not needed** such as **`CreatedDate`**, **`UpdatedDate`**, **`CreatedBy`** and many many more.

Comment: sir i have made the adjustment please check it once

Comment: Much better, thanks, but be sure to leave in the Date property that you want to filter by.

Comment: done sir, now expenditure records are recorded in the created date property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a Linq `Where()` clause for this. It will filter items using the condition specified, and the next statement will only use the filtered items.

```
var date = DateTime.Today;   // example date, change as needed
model.TotalExpenses = ent
    .Expenditures
    .Where(m => m.CreatedDate == date)
    .Sum(m => m.PaidPrice);
```

If your `CreatedDate` has a Time part other than 00:00:00 then you need to check for a range between the date and the next day:

```
var date = DateTime.Today;   // example date, change as needed
var nextDay = date.AddDays(1);
model.TotalExpenses = ent
    .Expenditures
    .Where(m => m.CreatedDate >= date && m.CreatedDate < nextDay)
    .Sum(m => m.PaidPrice);
```